# AttributeError: 'class' object has no attribute 'signal'

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

It's maybe a stupid question but why I can not emit a signal `self.printSecondSignal.emit('TEST2')` in the `Worker` class. What I want to do is: Calling the function `do_some_calc()` (connecteded over `QPushButton clicked() signal`)  from `TestMain` class and in `Worker` class, want to emit a signal to update the Gui in `TestMain`. But I get `AttributeError: TestMain object has no attribute printSecondSignal`. Emitting the signal `self.printFirstSignal.emit('TEST1')` works without any problem

**TestMain.py**

```
from source.Manager.TestManager import *

class TestMain(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent= None):
        super(TestMain, self).__init__(parent)

        # import ui
        loadUi('../gui/testGui.ui', self)

        self.manager= TestManager()
        self.thread= QThread()
        self.manager.moveToThread(self.thread)

        self.manager.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.manager.first_slot)
        self.thread.start()

        self.manager.printFirstSignal.connect(self.print_onTextEdit)
        self.offlinePushButton.clicked.connect(self.offline_slot)
        self.manager.printSecondSignal.connect(self.print_onTextEdit)

    def offline_slot(self):
        manager.do_some_calc(self)

    def print_onTextEdit(self, str):
        self.outputTextEdit.append(str)
```

**Manager.py**

```
class TestManager(QObject): #QtCore.QThread
    finished= pyqtSignal()
    printFirstSignal= pyqtSignal(str)
    printSecondSignal= pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent= None):
        super(TestManager, self).__init__(parent)

    def first_slot(self):
        self.printFirstSignal.emit('TEST1')
        self.finished.emit()

    def do_some_calc(self):
        do_sometingelse()
        try:
            self.printSecondSignal.emit('TEST2')
        except :
            traceback.print_exc()
```

Comment: gprManager.printSecondSignal is a typo ? it should be manager.print... ?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for that. I have corrected it now.

Comment: it should work so ? The typo explain the error.

Comment: You should always include the complete Traceback (formatted as code) in your question. Copy and paste it in the question then select (all of) it and type `ctrl-k`.

Comment: No it doesn't unfortunately. I get still same traceback. And how can I get code-based traceback?

Answer (score 0):

As you were told in the other question you asked about this same code, all communication between threads has to be done through use of a signal.  In your `offline_slot` method you attempt to call the `manager.do_some_calc()` directly while the manager instance is operating in another thread.  This communication will have to be done with a signal.  It would look something like this:

```
class TestMain(QMainWindow):

    do_some_calc_signal = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestMain, self).__init__(parent)

        # import ui
        loadUi('../gui/testGui.ui', self)

        self.manager= TestManager()
        self.thread= QThread()
        self.manager.moveToThread(self.thread)

        self.do_some_calc_signal.connect(self.manager.do_some_calc)

        self.manager.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.manager.first_slot)
        self.thread.start()

        self.manager.printFirstSignal.connect(self.print_onTextEdit)
        self.offlinePushButton.clicked.connect(self.offline_slot)
        self.manager.printSecondSignal.connect(self.print_onTextEdit)

    def offline_slot(self):
        self.do_some_calc_signal.emit()
```